# How do I link Azure with Office 365?

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365

I would like to know how do I get to sync our Office365 users with Azure.

Today our setup is like this:

- Office 365 syncs users with our on premisses Active Directory
- Azure does not have any connection with either Office 365 or on-prem IS

What I would need is to sync users from Office 365 to Azure, so that on Azure I would login with a Office 365 account(which actually is the on-prem Active Directory account).

Come to think about it, there could be one way, but don't know whether it would conflict with Azure AD Connect, but it's already being used with Office 365.

What do you think?

Comment: You are using Azure AD connect, so you have already sync'd users to Azure. `Azure AD Connect > Azure AD > Office365`

Comment: Please read the [help] to learn how our site works. We are not a discussion forum and you shouldn't use the answer functionality to trying to lead a discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no conflict. Basically, what you need to do is associate your existing tenant to Azure. In the backend, Office365 already uses Azure AD so you won't even be creating a new one.

Here's the official guide:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-add-office-365-tenant-to-azure-subscription/

Unfortunately, the new portal is still lacking full support for Azure AD hence the need to use the classic one.